# window.onbeforeunload not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a form  and it contains input fields ,gridview and buttons.I want to  warn Users about losing data when navigating away from Form .In Firefox (5),Chrome this works fine, but  IE it doesn't .Here i am giving my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setConfirmUnload(on) {

        window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;

    }
    function unloadMessage() {

        return 'You have entered new data on this page.' +
    ' If you navigate away from this page without' +
    ' first saving your data, the changes will be' +
    ' lost.';
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(':input', document.aspnetForm).bind(
         "change", function () {
         setConfirmUnload(true);
     }
        ); // Prevent accidental navigation away
    });
</script>
```

On submit button i declared `OnClientClick="setConfirmUnload(true);"`

Can anyone have any idea about this .Please help me

Thanks

Comment: I stripped out the jQuery `ready` function and just called `setConfirmUnload(true)` within the page and it worked properly.  My guess is either a) You have an error that is triggering under `IE` and not `Chrome` or  there is an `HTML` layout error which means your `selector` isn't working.  Put `console.log`  inside the ready statement and trace through what is happening there.

Comment: Thnks a lot..But my page containing many gridviews add buttons.If i am doing like according to you,on pagination of gridview also its showing the alert box.How to stop this alert in pagination.and in the next page of gridview if i am doing any changes the alert is not coming .Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You've not provided enough information.  I/we have no idea what your HTML looks like.  The only thing I can do is what I did -- point you to the most likely source of the problem to help you narrow things down.

Answer (score -1):

do this -

```
OnClientClick="return setConfirmUnload(true);"
```

Comment: `setConfirmUnload()` doesn't returning anything, so what's the point of using it with `return`?

Comment: this is from official microsoft site -http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/onbeforeunload.htm

Comment: Maybe it assumes that the function actually returns something. Or maybe you need to recommend that he change the function to return something.

Comment: That page doesn't mention `OnClientClick` at all, it's just about `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: I don't have any html code. I don't know the answer to his problem, but I'm pretty sure this isn't it.